# ReactJS Drag and Drop Between Multiple Lists

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I've been searching all day and haven't found anything.. All the React libraries all seem to only sort between ONE standalone list.

The closest I found was this article: http://rafaelquintanilha.com/sortable-targets-with-react-dnd/

with this example: http://rafaelquintanilha.com/apps/sortabletargets/

The problem is that you have to drag the item to a different list BEFORE you can sort it.  In otherwords you can't drag an item from one list to another list and also place the item exactly where you want in that list that your'e dragging it to.

Is there any sort of library that you guys know about or know just of any way I can accomplish this?

I desperately need this functionality for a work project.  Thank you for any help

Comment: I have the same question.. Did you found a solution ?

Comment: @Manuel, please see my response

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what I need

Answer (score 10):

This library is what you are looking for:

https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd

But be aware that it doesn't support virtualization at this point in time. [**UPDATE: Virtualization is now supported! July 2021**]

Here is the example with source code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ql08j35j3q

Comment: 2021 update: it now supports virtualization

Comment: @xeiton any idea on how should I solve this by using react dnd

Comment: @Jayavel did you find any way to do this with react dnd?

Comment: @PrinceAgrawal you can find the nested dropping between lists  here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dnd-nested-sortable-forked-16o2m?file=/src/Card.jsx

Comment: @Jayvel do you have code for drag from 1 list to another

Comment: @xeiton Seems this library is no-longer maintained. Do you have any recommendations for another good library to use? I've been scouring but most refer back to this react-dnd library.